# Angular print service timeout issue for multiple print

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

```
 var userServicePromise =   UserService.printBarCodes(sampleId);
                 userServicePromise.then(function(response) {
                    if (response != null && response.data != null && response.data.result != null) {

                    response.data.result.forEach(function(entry) { //three values in the array, iteraring three times.
                     $timeout(function() {
                        vm.barCodeImage = angular.copy(entry); 
                          $timeout(function() {
                             PrintService.printElement("printThisElement"); // display one value three times
                         }, 1);
                         }, 2);
                        }); 
                     } else {
                         toaster.error(response.data.message);
                     }
                 });
```

using print service to print the div, values of the div are populated using the variable(vm.barCodeImage).
But here one value is displaying all the time in the print. tried adding time out interval after the for each, but no luck.

//print service code

```
(function() {
 'use strict';
 angular.module('app.services')
  .factory('PrintService', PrintService);

 PrintService.$inject = [];

 function PrintService() {
  var service = {
   printElement: printElement
  };

  return service;



  function printElement(elem) {

   var printSection = document.getElementById('printSection');

   // if there is no printing section, create one
   if (!printSection) {
    printSection = document.createElement('div');
    printSection.id = 'printSection';
    document.body.appendChild(printSection);
   }
   var elemToPrint = document.getElementById(elem);
   // clones the element you want to print
   var domClone = elemToPrint.cloneNode(true);
   printSection.innerHTML = '';
   printSection.appendChild(domClone);
   window.print();

   window.onafterprint = function() {
    printSection.innerHTML = '';
   }
  };

 }
})();
```

The expected result for this should be three different print(suppose loop size is 3, it should be 7858,7859,7860), but here it displays all same. 
[image]

printThisElement id is an HTML.

```
 <div id="printThisElement" class="onlyprint" >
  <table>
    <tr> 
        <td>{{ ctrl.instCode }}</td>
        <td align="center">{{ ctrl.date  | dateDisplayFilter}}  </td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
        <td colspan="2" align="center"> <img ng-src="data:image/JPEG;base64,{{ctrl.barCodeImage}}"> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
        <td colspan="2" align="center">{{ ctrl.user.name }} </td>
    </tr>
        <tr> 
        <td >Reg Id: {{ ctrl.regIdLookup }}</td>
        <td align="center">{{ ctrl.testName }}</td>
    </tr>

  </table>
   </div>
```

Comment: Can you provide codes of PrintService ? And can you provide the single display value and the expected ?

Comment: Another question : what is '"printThisElement"' in your sample ? An id that reference a DOM element ?

Comment: yes it is an id that reference a DOM element

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I supposed your binding is wrong. printThisElement refer to single data in controller. So if you have multiple entries, it must be an array.

I suggest to you to use a directive instead of a service to print element in DOM.

I create a little plunker to illustrate it : https://plnkr.co/edit/QvmqV88wZCYbsehMWh3W?p=preview

This plunker show how from an array resulting of calling an async service you can display all entries.

The directive is very simple :

```
.directive('print', function() {
   return {
     restrict: 'E',
     scope: {
        data: '='
     },
     template: '<div id="printThisElement" class="onlyprint" ><table><tr> <td>{{ data.instCode }}</td></tr><tr><td>... Other values in data ...</td></tr></table></div>',
 }
})
```

The template of the directive is your printThisElement id. With this way you can display multiple result isolate by directive.

Hope this will help you

Edit : Solution for the problem was report on this stack [Inconsistent Data on multiple page printing on a printer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38713683/inconsistent-data-on-multiple-page-printing-on-a-printer)

Comment: I need to change the whole code structure for this ?

Comment: I think it's a better way. The problem in your code is you clone an element that contains angular binding. This binding refer single property. Is that what you have always same value in your three div. If you don't want change code structure you will be manage the array. 
I edited the plunker to use a service and generate div for each entries. But it's not the better and you risk to have other problems later.

Comment: For your sample with the service, you mustinject $compile and do : 

printSection.appendChild($compile(domClone)($childScope)[0]);

Comment: Why I need an array? Can't  I  print one page at a time ?, Also when I'm changing the timeout value it displays two different value sometimes.

Comment: Maybe i don't understand, you want to print one etiquette at time ? How do you do that with a loop on each entry ? I understood you want to display the 3 etiquette on a page

Comment: Miscommunication, I need to do three separate print.. due to time out it gives issue I guess.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118786/discussion-between-silvinus-and-user630209).

Comment: what is that $childScope ? Throwing exception as it is not injected.

Comment: I don't have this exception, but in line 31 of this plunker you should declare $childscope as 'var $childscope = $rootScope.$new()'

Comment: Instead of this  
defered.resolve([
          {instCode: 1},
          {instCode: 2},
          {instCode: 3}]);
      }, 1000)
   
  Can I use this way ?
   var tn = ['1', '2', '3', '4'];   
    angular.forEach(tn, function(item) {
    defered.resolve([
     {instCode: item}]);
    }, 1000) 
   
      })

Comment: var tn = ['1', '2', '3', '4'];
var result = [];
angular.forEach(tn, function(item) { result.push({instCode: item})  }, 1000) });
defered.resolve(result);

Comment: Its not returning the result value back, return $http.get(Constants.GET_BARCODE_FOR_SAMPLE_IDS+sampleId).then(function (response) { // response is {"code":0,"message":"Total 3 records found","result":["1","2","3"]}
         var defered = $q.defer();
        var result = []; 
          $timeout(function() {
         angular.forEach(response.data.result, function(item) { 
          console.log("item :"+item);
         result.push({barcode: item}) }, 1000) }); 
         defered.resolve(result); 
         console.log("result "+result);
         return defered.promise;
          });

Comment: in this case defer isn't needed. if your $http.get is in your controller. Just push result in scope variable.
$scope.barcodes = []
$http.get(Constants.GET_BARCODE_FOR_SAMPLE_IDS+sampleId)
 .then(function (response) { 
  // response is {"code":0,"message":"Total 3 records found","result":["1","2","3"]} 
  angular.forEach(response.data.result, function(item) { 
   console.log("item :"+item); 
   $scope.barcodes.push({barcode: item}) 
  };
 });

Comment: Thank you, then how will achieve multiple printing .. with different data.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38713683/inconsistent-data-on-multiple-page-printing-on-a-printer.. you have any solution for this, its the same issue in detail.